# How to hold header and footer position in LaTeX when using pdflscape to convert to landscape format

Tags: pdflscape

I am using `pdflscape` to convert my document to landscape in LaTeX/RMarkdown. I have an issue whereby the content in my header and footer has rotated, and I would prefer to keep it in its original position.
Is there any way which I could hold the logo to the top right-hand corner and the page number to the bottom right corner?

[image]

here is a small reproductible of the packages and header/footer that's in my `tex` file

```
% % % packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[left = 2.5cm, right = 2.5cm, top = 1.2cm, bottom = 1.2cm, includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multicol}




% % % header and footer ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{ \includegraphics{\logo}}
\makeatother
\newlength{\myheight}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\pagename~\thepage \hspace{1pt} / \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
```

Comment: If you want the whole document to be landscape, just give the `landscape` option to geometry and don't use the `pdflscape` package.

Comment: Thanks @PietervanOostrum